# Maximum and Minimum of complex number $z$ where $|z^4+z^3-z-1| = |z^4-z^3+z-1|$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z\in C$ satisfies $|z^4+z^3-z-1| = |z^4-z^3+z-1|.$ Then minimum value of $|z-1-2i|$ and maximum value of $|z^2-1-2i|$ is . . .

$\bf{Attempt}$ from $|z^4+z^3-z-1| = |z^4-z^3+z-1|$

$$|(z+1)(z^3-1)| = |(z-1)(z^3+1)|$$

$$\bigg|\frac{z-1}{z+1}\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{z^3-1}{z^3+1}\bigg|=k$$

Could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Your factorizations are incomplete.

$$  z^3 - 1 = (z-1)(z^2+z+1)  $$
$$  z^3 + 1 = (z+1)(z^2-z+1)  $$

This leaves $|z^2 -z +1| = |z^2 + z + 1|$ (having already extracted the factors $z-1$ and $z+1$).

Comment: Or $z=\pm1\dots$

Comment: Good point, @Michael!

Comment: @Eric: While true (so I won't be downvoting), this leaves the OP with no clues on how to approach ugly portion of the problem (so I won't be upvoting).

Comment: @CameronBuie : I assert that the other answers filled in all the steps following the hint.  Although OP asked for help (not full solutions), I'm not going to waste time on math.SE downvoting and flagging overresponsive answers.

Comment: Understood. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've gone just a bit astray.

First of all, since you don't know what $z$ is, it's dangerous to divide by $|z+1|,$ as it could well be equal to $0.$ In fact, $z=-1$ is a solution to the given equation, so that is entirely reasonable!

Next, you haven't quite finished factoring. Observing that $z=1$ is clearly a root of $z^3-1=0,$ then $z-1$ is a factor of $z^3-1.$ In particular, $$z^4+z^3-z-1=(z+1)(z-1)\left(z^2+z+1\right),$$ and similarly, $$z^4-z^3+z-1=(z-1)(z+1)\left(z^2-z+1\right).$$ Now, the given equation becomes $$|z+1||z-1|\left|z^2+z+1\right|=|z-1||z+1|\left|z^2-z+1\right|,$$ or equivalently, $$|z+1||z-1|\left(\left|z^2+z+1\right|-\left|z^2-z+1\right|\right)=0.$$ Thus, we can conclude that $z\in\{1,-1\}$ or that $\left|z^2+z+1\right|=\left|z^2-z+1\right|.$ It is easily verified that $z^2+z+1$ and $z^2-z+1$ are never both equal to $0,$ and neither is equal to $0$ when $z\in\{1,-1\}.$ Thus, assuming that the given equation holds and that $z\notin\{1,-1\},$ we have that $$\left|z^2+z+1\right|=\left|z^2-z+1\right|,\tag{1}$$ and you *could* divide through by one side of the equation safely.

However, we still don't have to do so. Since the modulus function is non-negative, then $(1)$ holds if and only if $$\left|z^2+z+1\right|^2=\left|z^2-z+1\right|^2\tag{2}$$ holds. Recall now the following facts (which hold for any $u,v,w\in\Bbb C$):

1. $|w|^2=w\cdot\overline w,$ where $\overline w$ is the complex conjugate of $w.$ In particular, if $w=x+iy$ for $x,y\in\Bbb R,$ then $|w|^2=x^2+y^2.$
2. $\overline{u+v}=\overline u+\overline v.$
3. $\overline{u\cdot v}=\overline u\cdot\overline v.$
4. For any $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\overline{\alpha}=\alpha.$
5. Applying facts 2-4 shows that $\overline{u-v}=\overline u-\overline v.$
6. $\overline{\left(\overline w\right)}=w.$
7. The real part of $w$ is $\Re(w)=\frac12\left(w+\overline w\right).$

With these facts at our disposal, we see that $$\begin{eqnarray}\left|z^2+z+1\right|^2 &=& \left(z^2+z+1\right)\cdot\overline{(z^2+z+1)}\\ &=& \left[\left(z^2+1\right)+z\right]\cdot\left[\overline{(z^2+1)}+\overline z\right]\\ &=& \left|z^2+1\right|^2+\overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)+z\cdot\overline{\left(z^2+1\right)}+|z|^2\\ &=& \left|z^2+1\right|^2+|z|^2+2\Re\left(\overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)\right),\end{eqnarray}$$ and similarly that $$\left|z^2-z+1\right|^2=\left|z^2+1\right|^2+|z|^2-2\Re\left(\overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)\right),$$ whence we see that $(2)$ is equivalent to $$\Re\left(\overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)\right)=0.\tag{3}$$ From there, $$\begin{eqnarray}0 &=& 2\Re\left(\overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)\right)\\ &=& \overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)+z\cdot\overline{\left(z^2+1\right)}\\ &=& \overline z\cdot\left(z^2+1\right)+z\cdot\left(\left(\overline z\right)^2+1\right)\\ &=& |z|^2\cdot z+z+|z|^2\cdot\overline z+\overline z\\ &=& \left(|z|^2+1\right)\cdot z+\left(|z|^2+1\right)\cdot\overline z\\ &=& 2\left(|z|^2+1\right)\Re(z),\end{eqnarray}$$ so since $|z|^2+1\ne 0,$ then we have that $(3)$ is equivalent to $$\Re(z)=0.\tag{4}$$

Thus, letting $A:=\{1,-1\}\cup\{\alpha i:\alpha\in\Bbb R\},$ the given equation holds if and only if $z\in A.$

---

At this point, we need only minimize $|z-1-2i|$ and maximize $\left|z^2-1-2i\right|$ among these points.

Suppose that $z=\alpha i$ for some real $\alpha.$ Observe that $z$ minimizes $|z-1-2i|$ if and only if $z$ minimizes $$|z-1-2i|^2=|-1+i(\alpha-2)|^2=(-1)^2+(\alpha-2)^2=(\alpha-2)^2+1.$$ Since $(\alpha-2)^2\ge0$ for all real $\alpha,$ then $\alpha=2$ clearly minimizes $(\alpha-2)^2+1.$ Thus for $z\in A,$ the minimum value of $|z-1-2i|$ occurs at some point $z\in\{1,-1,2i\}.$ I leave it to you to determine said minimum value.

Similarly, if $z=\alpha i$ for some real $\alpha,$ then $z$ maximizes $\left|z^2-1-2i\right|$ if and only if $z$ maximizes $$\left|z^2-1-2i\right|=(\alpha^2+1)^2+4.$$ Is this possible?